# Jquery file upload with two model associated in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I follow the tutorial of Ryan Bates that Jquery file upload but the example was only 1 model. I tried to make a version for my application that serviceproviders has_many photos and photos belongs_to serviceprovider.

This is my new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a Clearance</h1>

<%= form_for Clearance.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :avatar, "Clearances" %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true, name: "clearance[avatar]" %> 
<% end %>
```

Clearance controller

`def new
        @serviceprovider = Serviceprovider.find(params[:serviceprovider_id]
        @clearance = @serviceprovider.clearances.new
    end`

```
def create
    @clearance = Clearance.create(clearance_params)
end
```

And I got an error `undefined method "clearances_path"`
How can I upload a photo with associated models. Thank you!

---

**

### Update

**

I'm trying to create a galleries of photo of clearances for Serviceproviders. For example a serviceproviders has a Police clearance, NBI Clearance and any clearances that may notify that he had no any criminal cases. Now I can upload the photo using the jquery-fileupload (thanks for @OlivierLance for helping me) but now I want every time I upload the photo it will automatically display. I new to rails and I have a hard time to learn some gems because as I said I'm not familiar in rails. I already the solutions that I will reload the page so that it will display every time I upload but nothings happen. The page had a infinite loop redirecting the page.

```
def new
        @serviceprovider = Serviceprovider.find(params[:serviceprovider_id])
        @clearance = @serviceprovider.clearances.new

        @clearances = @serviceprovider.clearances
                redirect_to new_serviceprovider_clearance_url(@serviceprovider)
        end
    end 

def create
    @serviceprovider = Serviceprovider.find(params[:clearance][:serviceprovider_id])
    @clearance = @serviceprovider.clearances.create(clearance_params)
end
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: this answer is only valid if you intend to have your `new` page handle a single `Clearance` addition to a specific `Serviceprovider` instance**

Let's clarify the cause of the error you get: what Rails is telling you, is that you're trying to create a form for a `Clearance` object but it doesn't know where to send the creation `POST` request to (the URL that would end up in the `action` attribute of the generated `<form>` tag).

You will have to add routes for Rails to match URLs to actions of your `ClearancesController`. The minimal addition you should make in your `routes.rb` file is:

```
resources :clearances, only: [:create]
```

I assume you already have a nested route within the service providers' routes to display the new clearance form.

This new route will create a new route helper, `clearances_path`, as it is described in the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
Now that this route exists, Rails will be able to generate the form for a new `Clearance` object.

However there are a few fixes you need to apply to your current code.

First, your form is built using `Clearance.new`. `Clearance.new` will return a new, naked, disowned `Clearance` object (poor one!). What you need though, is a new object that belongs to the `clearances` collection of the `Serviceprovider` you're adding it to.

Luckily enough, you have created one of these in the `new` action of your controller. Why not use it? :)

```
# new.html.erb
<h1>Add a Clearance</h1>

<%= form_for @clearance do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :serviceprovider_id %>
    <%= f.label :avatar, "Clearances" %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true, name: "clearance[avatar]" %> 
<% end %>
```

And why does it matter? Well because this `Clearance` object has been initialized with a non-null `serviceprovider_id` (assuming that's the name of your foreign key). Note that I have added an hidden field that will hold this id within the form.

With all this in place, when you submit your form, it'll go to your `create` action and create a new `Clearance` object within your database that will be correctly associated to the `Serviceprovider` you wanted.

Considering the content of your question, that's how far I can answer. I guess you got the file upload/saving right by following Ryan Bates' tutorial. If not, you'll need to add details about what you did/did not do and what's actually failing there!

(PS: you should definitely rename your `Serviceprovider` class to `ServiceProvider`)
**Update**

`new` is the action that will display your form and your already uploaded images. `create` is the action that is called when you submit the form. What you want, is go back to the `new` page once a clearance has been added: move your `redirect_to` to the end of the `create` action instead of `new`.

Comment: Thank you so much @OlivierLance .. I got it but now I have a problem how can I display each photo uploaded.  I have here in my new method `@serviceprovider = Serviceprovider.find(params[:serviceprovider_id])
  @clearance = @serviceprovider.clearances.new

  @clearances = @serviceprovider.clearances` so that every time I upload it also display but I got an error undefined avatar_url. but also my concern is that my solution is really a functioning?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz I don't have enough information to reply to this... you should update your question with details about what you're using to manage the uploaded files and what you want to achieve.

Comment: See my updated answer! If you have troubles displaying the images once you are on the `new` page, I suggest you accept my answer to close this question and create a new question where you describe your new problem.

Comment: Ok @OlivierLance.. I will make a new thread for this. btw, thank you for your help and also your update solution didn't worked but I will post the full details in the next thread so that you have the idea what happening inside. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You're welcome!
Put the link to your new question here and I'll have a look :)
Can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235